# Is VB.NET PrinterSettings and DefaultPageSettings able to read all the properties of a printer or only the "standard" ones?

Tags: .net, vb.net, printing

I am using Visual Studio 2012, and need to get and set the properties of a printer through my code, but using the standard functions of VB.NET I just can obtain the "standard" values of the printer and the document. This is my code:

```
PrintDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings = PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings
PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Brother MFC-8950DW Printer"
PrintDialog1.AllowSomePages = True
' This is just to show the properties while debugging
MsgBox(PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings.ToString)
MsgBox(PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.ToString)
If PrintDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
    PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings = PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings
    'PrintDocument1.Print()
```

These are the properties I can obtain for any printer I have configured in my computer:

[image]

[image]

This is fine to obtain the standard properties of a printer, but I can not obtain some very specific parameters of the printer I am using, like for instance printing both sides of the paper. If I open directly the Windows printer dialog of the printer I want to use (Brother in the example), I can set the property of printing both sides of the paper, but I guess that this property can not be obtained by PrinterSettings or DefaultPageSettings because I can not see it in the debugging results shown above.

So my guessing is that probably it is necessary a direct library API of the printer to set or get those parameters. In my case the printer of my client is a Fuji-Xerox ApeosPort-IV (able to print both sides, staple documents, and other non-standard functions) but there is not such API for .NET.

Please if somebody had this kind of problem before I would appreciate very much 
just to confirm if it is possible to get those specific properties of a printer through the standard .NET functions or not. I did the research and initially I think is not possible, but if I could get some feedback here to confirm if I am correct or know how to do it would be very appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also found that I couldn't use the normal functions.

I ended up getting the settings from the registry.

The key is:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE | SYSTEM | CurrentControlSet | Control | Print | Printers
```